# Why form design is not visible?

Tags: java, netbeans

Unfortunately i deleted my form file from source package.Then I restored that file but the form design is not visible in netbeans IDE.
how i can see the form design? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have your 1- restarted Netbeans and/or 2- Deleted the user cache and restarted Netbeans?

Comment: yes, I restarted netbeans

Comment: Did you remove the cache?  Did you try rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yes i rebuild it but didn't remove the cache.

Comment: which version of NB you are using? check local history in netbeans

Comment: I am using NetBeans 5.5

Comment: source have both the form file and java file of my project but in IDE, form design is not visible.Please help !!